Within traditional DMRG, how do I calculate a reduced density matrix?
At every step of traditional DMRG (one that does not involve tensor networks), one truncates the entanglement spectrum an uses the truncated Hilbert space to add new sites. This prevents the exponential increase of the Hamiltonian matrix size.
However, suppose I want to calculate the reduced density matrix $\rho_1=\text{Tr}_1[\rho]$ of the first lattice site, when the total system has $N$ sites and appropriate truncations have been carried out to get to this point. Here, $\rho=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ is the density matrix for the ground state and $\text{Tr}_1$ is the partial trace over all sites except the first. If I were using exact diagonalisation, I would construct the ground state in the real space basis (of size $2^{N}$ for spinless fermions) and then the partial trace procedure is straightforward, since I know which positions in the basis correspond to the first site.
However, within DMRG, the truncated basis no longer retains information of the sites (at least not directly, because it is not of size $2^N$); hence, how do I carry out the partial trace operation using the truncated basis?
